# Number of positive solutions vs number of non-negative solutions to an equation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was reading Sheldon Ross' A first Introduction to Probability, where he says that the number of positive integer valued solutions to:

$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + ............. + x_{r} = n, x_{i} > 0, i = 1,2,....r$ is: $n-1\choose r-1$

On the other hand the number of non-negative solutions to to :

$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + ............. + x_{r} = n$ is $n+r-1\choose r-1$.

Can someone please tell me what the difference is between the two equations? The way I look at it both these combinations are doing the same thing. If not, why?

Comment: $x_i>0$ vs $x_i\ge 0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics), https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive means the values must all be greater than $0$.

Nonnegative means the values could be $0$.  There will obviously be more options if you allow zero values than if you don't.

Let's take the second equation as given (google stars and bars to find out why it is true):

> The number of solutions to $x_1 + ... + x_r = n$ where $x_i \ge 0$ is ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$.

The number of solutions to $x_1 + ..... + x_r =n$ where $x_i \ne 0; x_i \ge 1$ must be a smaller number because for each $x_i$ we have one fewer choice.

But if $x_1 + .... + x_r = n$ then

$(x_1-1) + ..... + (x_r-1) =n-r$ and $x_i -1 \ge 0$ is the exact same equations (well, an *equivalent* equation-- an equation that has the exact same solutions).

We can rewrite that as $y_1 + ... +y_r = m$ where $m=n-r$ and $y_i=x_i -1 \ge 0$.

So we know the number of solutions to that is ${m+r -1\choose r-1} = {(n-r)+r -1\choose r-1} = {n-1\choose r-1}$.

So

> The number of solutions to $x_1 + ... + x_r = n$ where $x_i > 0$ is ${n-1\choose r-1}$.

And

> The number of solutions to $x_1 + ... + x_r = n$ where $x_i > 0$ is ${n-1\choose r-1}$ which is *less* than ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$ which is the number of solutions to $x_1 + ... + x_r = n$ where $x_i \ge 0$